# InputStream, return to beginning

Tags: c#, validation, stream, asp.net-mvc-5, inputstream

I have a controller post method, which requires an uploaded file:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadCSV", "TemporaryPerson", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="personFile" /><input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
}
```

and controller method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadCSV(UploadCsvViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
                {
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                    {
                        var records = csv.GetRecords<TemporaryPersonCsv>().ToList();
                        foreach (var record in records)
                        {
//...................
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
       }
```

it works and works fine. But I want to move all validations to UploadCsvViewModel:

```
public class UploadCsvViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files == null || HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count == 0 || HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].ContentLength == 0)
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("File is not selected or empty", new string[] { "NoFile" }));

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                var enumeraterecords = csv.GetRecords<TemporaryPersonCsv>();

                if (enumeraterecords != null)
                {
                    var records = enumeraterecords.ToList();
                    if (records == null || records.Count == 0)
                        results.Add(new ValidationResult("No records in file", new string[] { "NoRecords" }));

                    // different validation, according with business logic

                }
                else
                    results.Add(new ValidationResult("No records in file", new string[] { "NoRecords" }));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Problem is if I have Validate method in UploadCsvViewModel, then I get error:

> Exception Details: CsvHelper.CsvReaderException: No header record was
>   found.

on line:

```
var records = csv.GetRecords<TemporaryPersonCsv>().ToList();
```

in controller method. I assume, that InputStream has invalid position. I tried:

1. copy to another stream:

   ```
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(ms, HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
   ```

no help

2. set input stream position to 0 on the end of validate method:

   HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream.Position = 0;

no help

3. call DiscardBufferedData for 'reader' object

   ```
           reader.DiscardBufferedData();
   ```

no help too.

Comment: Do you really want to read the file twice, just to do the validation of its contents?

Comment: any another approach to validate data in Validate method of model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I copy InputStream to another stream (i.e. MemoryStream), then I can set Position=0 for both streams (InputStream and MemoryStream) and it works.

Validation method:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files == null || HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count == 0 || HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].ContentLength == 0)
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("File is not selected or empty", new string[] { "NoFile" }));

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                {
                    var enumeraterecords = csv.GetRecords<TemporaryPersonCsv>();

                    if (enumeraterecords != null)
                    {
                        var records = enumeraterecords.ToList();
                        if (records == null || records.Count == 0)
                            results.Add(new ValidationResult("No records in file", new string[] { "NoRecords" }));

                        // find dublicates in CSV file
                        var dublicates = (records.GroupBy(p => p.Fullname.ToLower().Trim()).Where(p => p.Count() > 1).Select(p => p.Key)).ToList();
                        if (dublicates != null && dublicates.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var dublicateFullname in dublicates)
                            {
                                results.Add(new ValidationResult(String.Concat("There are 2 or more records with fullname='", dublicateFullname, "' in your csv file. Please, fix your file and upload again."), new string[] { "DublicateRecords" }));
                            }
                        }

                        // find dublicates in TemporaryPersons and Persons tables
                        PlugandabandonEntities db = new PlugandabandonEntities();
                        foreach (var record in records)
                        {
                            if (db.TemporaryPerson.Where(p => p.Fullname.ToLower() == record.Fullname.ToLower()).Count() > 0)
                                results.Add(new ValidationResult(String.Concat("Record with fullname='", record.Fullname, "' already exists in TemporaryPersons. Please, fix your file and upload again."), new string[] { "RecordExistsInTemporaryPerson" }));

                            if (db.Person.Where(p => p.Fullname.ToLower() == record.Fullname.ToLower()).Count() > 0)
                                results.Add(new ValidationResult(String.Concat("Record with fullname='", record.Fullname, "' already exists in Persons. Please, fix your file and upload again."), new string[] { "RecordExistsInPersons" }));
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        results.Add(new ValidationResult("No records in file", new string[] { "NoRecords" }));
                }

                reader.DiscardBufferedData();
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream.Position = 0;

        return results;
    }
```

then we have a "virgin" InputStream in controller method and we can work with it as we want ;)